# How to define application localisation in Android

Tags: android, localization

Can someone tell how i can set the default locale of my application to English regardless the users settings...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

just modify the file(build/core/Makefile) setting PRODUCT_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE and PRODUCT_DEFAULT_REGION to what you want to set... to English in this case